# Keyboard event fires only on second button press

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to make a custom select box in svelte and i am using "use actions" for keyboard navigation and trapping focus.
What I have done so far :

```
const trapFocus = (node:HTMLElement, handler:(e:KeyboardEvent)=>void) : {destroy : () => void} => {
        const onFocus = (event:KeyboardEvent) => node && handler(event);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', onFocus, true);
        return {
            destroy() {
                document.removeEventListener('keydown', onFocus, true);
            }
        }
    }
const trapFocushandler = (e:KeyboardEvent) => {
        const focusableElements = focusContainer.querySelectorAll('button')
        const target = e.target as HTMLElement;

        let firstFocusableElement = focusableElements[0];
        let lastFocusableElement = focusableElements[focusableElements.length - 1];

        if (showOptions) {
            if (e.key==="Tab") {
                if (e.shiftKey) {
                    if (document.activeElement === firstFocusableElement) {
                        lastFocusableElement.focus();
                        e.preventDefault();                     
                    }
                } else {
                    if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableElement) {
                        firstFocusableElement.focus();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            } else if (e.key==="ArrowUp") {
                if (target.previousElementSibling) {
                    (target.previousElementSibling as HTMLElement).focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    lastFocusableElement.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            } else if (e.key==="ArrowDown") {
                if (document.activeElement !== firstFocusableElement) {
                    firstFocusableElement.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                if (target.nextElementSibling) {
                    (target.nextElementSibling as HTMLElement).focus();
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                } else {
                    firstFocusableElement.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
<div class="options {showOptions? 'open' : 'closed'}" tabindex="-1" bind:this={focusContainer} use:trapFocus={trapFocushandler}>
   {#each searchableOptions as option}
      <button id="option-{option.id}">{option.name}</button>
   {/each}
</div>
```

the problem occurs in ```if (e.key === "ArrowDown") block, when the options div is open and  arrow down is pressed the event fires only on second arrow press.
How can I get the correct behavior.

Comment: You're adding an event handler inside the callback of another event handler. That's why. And doing so is a code-smell and you should avoid it.